# How to connect to a sqlserver database without internet

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014

I want to create a desktop application using vb.net and sql-server. I have two computers and I have my sql-server installed in one of the machines (server) in this case. I want to access the database from that (server) using another computer but the challenge is, I don't have any internet connection. All I have is a network cable to connect these two computers the one serving as a server and the client machine. Is this possible to access my database or can only be achieved over an internet connection? If possible how can I go about it?

Comment: I would suggest that connecting to a database on the LAN, rather than the WAN, is just as common as the other. What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: I used to connect to ms access using \\computername\Disk\path for database sharing so I am asking is it possible with sql server database and how should the path look like? forgive me i am new to this

Comment: You don't connect to a database file in SQL Server, Seru, you connect to the instance. There is plenty of documentation, articles, and tutorials on how to connect to a SQL Server instance if you search for it.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, if you only need to connect two computers, you'll not even need a switch or hub. You only need to assign both computers a private IP address in the same address space, such as 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3 for computer A and B.

However, it might still be reasonable to use a switch for your purpose, as you might need to expand your network and/or connect to the internet in future cases, but in your particular case, it is not mandatory.